# AWS s3bucket "can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str"

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

Im having trouble finding out whats the problem. I don't know what's causing the error if its boto3 or s3bucket , DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage' seems to be the problem. At least when I remove DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE the templates render.
I either get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode' and 'ImageFieldFile' object is not subscriptable' for my dashboardview or
"can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str" attempting to upload image.

settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent




ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["herokuapp.com", 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Products.apps.ProductsConfig',
    'Users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'django_filters',
    'crispy_forms',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'storages',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Ecommerce.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'Products.context_processors.Products_and_Users',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Ecommerce.wsgi.application'



DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT'),
    }
}



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


GEOIP = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "Products")


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")



DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'Users.Profile'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = os.environ.get('AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH')
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = os.environ.get('AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE')
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACESSS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACESSS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')


if os.getcwd == '/app':
    DEBUG = False
```

Comment: when you use `get` function to return a value, it will return None in case you are don't have a specific key within the dictionary, my recommendation is to check if all the values are available in dictionary or not.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I now updated the question . I'm also getting 'ImageFieldFile' object is not subscriptable'.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, apparently I was was supposed to use AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID.

Comment: What does `AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ` refer to? That's not in the code and it's not an AWS-defined environment variable. Also, the access key and secret key are very much *not* interchangeable.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean they where interchangeable.

Comment: No problem, glad it’s resolved.

Comment: But you did have a point. I initially thought it was my environment  variables not loading  properly so I restarted my machine, and it didn't work. I even set the variables as a string thinking the environment variables was the problem but it still didn't work. I started reading the Django-storages docs and found AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY as an option and tried it and It worked. But reading your question got me thinking and I reverted back to AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACESSS_KEY and it works.

Comment: Now I'm really confused as to what was wrong initially with AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACESSS_KEY , and why AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID even worked because technically it shouldn't have had, like you stated " it's not an AWS-defined environment variable".

Comment: It looks like django-storages [supports both](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/master/storages/backends/s3boto3.py#L247) environment variables (the typical AWS env variables and some custom-named django S3 env variables that they made up).

Comment: That's what I figured, because it made completely no sense. Thanks for the help!